# Regex to replace a substring which is not contained into tags

Tags: java, regex

In the following string:

`a:b + <a:b> + a:b +a:b+ <a:b>+{a:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])+a:b * + <a:b> + {a:b}`

I have to replace a:b when not contained in <> or {}, a:b can be contained in spaces or operators, hence the expected result should be:

`x + <a:b> + x +x+ <a:b>+{a:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])+x * x + {a:b}`

I'm using the following regex:

`(^|[^<^{])a:b`

and the following code:

```
String st = "a:b + <a:b> + a:b +a:b+ <a:b>+{a:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])+a:b * + <a:b> + {a:b}";
    
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|[^<^{])a:b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
        
String s2 = matcher.replaceAll("x");
```

but I get:

`x + <a:b> +x x+ <a:b>+{a:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])x * + <a:b> + {a:b}`

How can I avoid to replace spaces and operators?

Comment: why should the last `<a:b>` be replaced? (and you should probably use zero-width lookahead/-behind for the delimiters)

Comment: (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#pos_lookahead))

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regex which explicitly matches NOT `<>` or `{}` around `a:b` and build your replacement using the matched groups:

```
String source = "a:b + <a:b> + a:b +a:b+ <a:b>+{a:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])+a:b * + <a:b> + {a:b}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|[^<{])(a:b)([^>}]|$)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(source);
String output = m.replaceAll("$1x$3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there's a few ways to do this "really properly" from a regexp perspective and they're all pretty messy. Maybe "slightly less ugliest" way is to use a combination of lookahead and negative lookbehind – match against `a:b` and then check that it isn't actually surrounded by `<>` or `{}`:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a:b(?=$|.(?<!<a:b>|{a:b}))");
```

The pattern breaks down as:

```
   a:b              # Find "a:b"
   (?=              # but only if it is followed by ...
     $ |            # the end of the string, or ...
     .(?<!          # the string that we just matched does NOT match ...
       <a:b>|{a:b}  # ... either of our exempt strings.
      )
   )
```

If you can assume that your input is well-formed and doesn't contain curly bits like `{a:b>` then @tobifasc's answer is a far better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex for matching:

```bash
(?<!<(?=...>))(?<!\{(?=...}))\ba:b\b
```

and replace this with `x`.

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LIuHz2)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XLMFaj/1)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `(?<!<(?=...>))`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have a `<` before the current position which must be followed by 3 characters (i.e. `a:b`) and `>`
- `(?<!\{(?=...}))`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if we have a `{` before the current position which must be followed by 3 characters and `}`
- `\ba:b\b`: Match `a:b` surrounded with word boundaries

**Java Code:**

```
String st = "a:b + <a:b> + a:b +a:b+ <a:b>+{a:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])+a:b * + <a:b> + {a:b}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "(?<!<(?=...>))(?<!\\{(?=...}))\\ba:b\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(st);
String s2 = matcher.replaceAll("x");
System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that in the example given in the question `'a'`, '`b'` and so on are placeholders and not literals. Therefore, the regular expression that works for `'a:b <c:d>'` should, without change, also work for `'e:f <g:h>'`. I have assumed it should also work for `'dog_1:cat_9 {3 little pigs: and 1 big, bad wolf}'` (where `'dog_1:cat_9'` is to be replaced with `'x'`), the only requirement being that the replacement strings be comprised of one or more word characters (letters, digits and underscores) followed by a colon followed by one or more word characters.

You could match the following regular expression

```
<[^>:]+:[^>]+>|\{[^}:]+:[^}]+}|(\w+:\w+)
```

and replace captured strings with `'x'`. The "Demo" link below considers the following two strings.

```
a:b + <a:b> + a:b +a:b+ <a:b>+{ac:b} + {a:b}+d([<a:b>])+a:b
ccc   mmmmm   ccc  ccc  mmmmm mmmmmm   mmmmm    mmmmm   ccc    

a bc:de <b c: d e> a dog:cat[de :f]
  ccccc mmmmmmmmmm   ccccccc
```

I have used `'m'`'s to denote strings that are matched but not captured, and `'c'`'s to denote strings that are matched *and* captured (to group 1).

Captures are to be replaced with `'x'`. No action is to be taken for strings that are matched but not captured.

This idea of matching, but not capturing, what you don't want and capturing only the juicy bits has been an established technique since I was a kid.

Naturally, this regular expression would need to be modified if my assumptions about requirements are incorrect.

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fax9A9/1)

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
<         match '<'
  [^>:]+  match one or more characters other than '>' and ':'
  :       march ':'
  [^>]+   match one or more characters other than '>'
>         match '>'
|         or
\{        match '{' 
  [^}:]+  match one or more characters other than '}' and ':'
  :       march ':'
  [^}]+   match one or more characters other than '}'
}         match '}'
|         or
(         begin capture group 1
  \w+     match one or more word characters
  :       march ':'
  \w+     match one or more word characters
)         end capture group 1
```

---

One may alternatively match the same regular expression without the capture group,

```
<[^>:]+:[^>]+>|\{[^}:]+:[^}]+}|\w+:\w+
```

and replace (with 'x') those matches that begin with a word character.

Answer (score 0):

With Java not having conditionals, both pairs need to be explicitly excluded.

```
a:b(?<!<a:b(?=>))(?<!\{a:b(?=}))
```

https://regex101.com/r/DzBzgq/1

```
 a:b
 (?<!
    <a:b
    (?= > )
 )
 (?<!
    \{a:b
    (?= } )
 )
```